# How to create a data frame which increases in size inside the loop?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 240*870 size. I used independent sample test to select only variables which have p-value <0.05 and copy them to another data frame.
I declared the data frame to be empty initially

```
fff<-data.frame()
```

Then wrote this code:

```
fea_names=names(test)

for( i in 1:length(test))
{
t_test<-t.test(test[,i]~State)
if(t_test$p.value<0.05)
{
cat("feature label->",fea_names[i],"and p-value is->",t_test$p.value,"\n")
**imp$fea_namesi]<-test$fea_names[i]**
}
}
```

It's not working. How to initialize a data frame which increases in size over the time?

Comment: sry.. imp<-data.frame()

Comment: So you want a selection of the columns of original data frame consisting only of those with a significant p-value from a t-test against `State`?

Comment: You refer to `fea_names` once and to `test$fea_names` in another place. Is `fea_names` a column of `test` or not? (It's unlikely it is, since it sounds like it's the same length as the number of columns of `test`, not the number of rows

Comment: Data frames, matrices, vectors, etc. don't have a static size in R. You can `cbind` or `rbind` at each iteration of a loop or `df[[i]]` to add an item. Doesn't matter how it was initialized so long as it was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this data.frame with `apply`, which applies a function to the columns of a dataset:

```
imp <- data.frame(fea_names = names(test),
                  p.value = apply(test, 2, function(e) t.test(e ~ State)$p.value))
```

Then you can filter out the rows with a p-value greater than .05:

```
imp <- subset(imp, p.value < .05)
```

Comment: Thx david, I just gave it a go but it resulted in the following error,         error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @user3473600 Are any of your columns of `test` factors, or character vectors, rather than numeric vectors? For instance, please perform `table(sapply(test, class))` and let me know the result.

Comment: Hi David, Yes there is one attribute(State) which is factor, do you mean to say that even         t.test(State~State)             is being performed and that is why I am getting that error.

Comment: @user3473600 yes, that's correct. You need to remove that column before using apply

Comment: I removed the "State" attribute and ran the following code  'imp <- data.frame(fea_names = names(test),
                  p.value = apply(test, 2, function(e) t.test(e ~ State)$p.value))' and subset the attributes which have p<0.05 using  'imp <- subset(imp, p.value < .05)' gave me date frame (38*2) which are having p-values<0.05, but the question remains same how to subset these attributes from 'test' data frame??

Comment: Thx very much @David Robinson. I have got it.                                          `imp->subset(imp,p<0.05)` `imp_fea<-t(imp[,1])`  ` test_new<-subset(test,select=c(imp_fea))`        and it worked.